# How do I know the number of times a value occur in a mysqli selection

Tags: php, mysqli

Please how do I know the number of times david has a vote of 2

```
Name  | Vote
-------------
|Gabri| 2
|David| 2
|Janny| 3
|David| 1
|David| 2
|Fally| 3
```

Comment: `select count(*) from thetable where Name="David" and Vote=2`

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html

Comment: Okay thanks for the reply but how do I return the value if the vote is found

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = "SELECT count(*) from table_name WHERE Name= 'David' and Vote=2";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
$fetch = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($fetch);
echo "<pre>";
```

outputs

```
Array
(
    [count(*)] => 4
)
```

to get the value you need just `echo $fetch['count(*)']; //outputs 4`

Answer (score 0):

```
select Name , count(Name) where Name = 'David' group by Name having count(Name) =2
```